# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS when parsing rest API http response on class

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

I made a small test app that fetches user data from server through rest api. Server responses the data as JSON data. The problem is, that when im trying to parse that data in User class, my applicatin crashes with execpion:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS
```

When I parse the json data in the viewcontroller, it works.
Here is a preview to the code that crashes:

ViewController.swift:

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var dataAsString: String = NSString(data: self.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, 
                                   options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
                                   error: nil) as NSDictionary
    var results: NSDictionary    = jsonResult["results"] as NSDictionary
    var userData: NSDictionary   = results["user"] as NSDictionary

    let user: User = User(initFromJSONData: userData)
```

User.swift:

```
init(initFromJSONData user: NSDictionary) {
    self.id = user["id"] as Int
```

It crashes to the user["id"] as Int. When i'm doing this exactly same thing on ViewController, it works. Would someone be able to explain why does it works like this? How this should be done?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber` can't be cast directly to `Int`. Try this:

```
let id = user["id"] as NSNumber
self.id = id.integerValue
```